# Send Windows Logs to a LogStash om_ssl

Tags: windows, logstash, event-log, nxlog

I try to send the windows log to a LogStash, but i receive a error, the same at the post:

[Using nxlog to ship logs in to logstash from Windows using om_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789903/using-nxlog-to-ship-logs-in-to-logstash-from-windows-using-om-ssl/32187253#32187253)

I tried to change my nxlog.conf like on the post, but not success.

I don't know, where is the file (template) for the generating a SSL (nxlog-ca-rules.cnf), how i generate this new certificate?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. There are several ways of creating a valid certificate infrastructure. Which OS do you use at your logstash server? Do you want to create a self signed certificate or do you have an existing CA which can sign a CSR for you? You don't need to stick to to the way of that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789903/using-nxlog-to-ship-logs-in-to-logstash-from-windows-using-om-ssl). You can create valid certificates with a tool of your choice. I ship logs with nxlog from Windows to Ubuntu. The certificates were created with openssl. I can tell you the necessary steps if you like