# Using TLS 1.2 to ship from NXlog to Logstash

Tags: ssl, logstash, nxlog

This is closely related to

- [Using nxlog to ship logs in to logstash from Windows using om_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789903/using-nxlog-to-ship-logs-in-to-logstash-from-windows-using-om-ssl)
- [Using SSL to ship from NXlog to Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294127/using-ssl-to-ship-from-nxlog-to-logstash)

I have a working NXlog and Logstash configuration as described in the above links.

However, the TLS connection fails with following exception in the logstash log:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
```

It seems that NXlog relies on SSLv3 instead of TLS 1.x to do the SSL handshake. However, the former has been disabled in recent Java versions (as used by logstash) due to the POODLE vulnerability.

So how can I disable SSLv3 on the client side and force NXlog to use TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to answer this one myself (after getting help on the NXlog community forum).

TLS is only supported by nxlog-ce-2.9.1347 and later.